# Return function within a .then

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have the following problem with Cypress asynchronous behaviour.
I need to create a fuction method that will take a parameter from a URL and return it because it will be used in different places later

So the method will look like this:

```
getParameterFromUrl(): string {
  cy.url().then(url => {
    cy.log(url);
    const parameterFromUrl = url.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    cy.log(paramterFromUrl);
    // return parameterFromUrl   I know this doesnt work because is within a then
  }
}
```

then in a lot of parts of the test I will need to take this parameter and use it:

```
const parameter = onMyPageObject.getParameterFromUrl();

cy.log(parameter)
```

of course I know this is undefined. I have checked a lot of possible solutions but any convince me since I have to explit the code everywhere with the then outside and match the regular expression everywhere (something I don't like at all).
The wait just works for request so I can even using it.

What can I do to change the async behaviour in this case to do something as simple as this?

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases

Comment: I alreadyd read it but I as I said doesnt explain how to avaoid repeating the regular expression over and over and over, so if you could explain it to me I will appreciate it instead of just adding the doc I have already read it

Comment: You're not returning anything in `getParameterFromUrl`, are you sure that `cy.url()` is indeed a `Promise`?

Comment: It _does_ explain how to avoid repeating the regex, you use an _alias_ for the resulting value.

Comment: the acces to the method is within a complete different class not in a before each within the same class that why I have to use a return, also in the doc explain that with an invoque taht already take the text doesnt make any logic in between

Comment: Ok I found the way but not excatly as shown in the doc but with alias thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to just return the chain from your method.

The `.then(... return parameterFromUrl)` simply modifies what you return, but you have to return the whole chain and treat it like a `Chainable<string>`.

```js
getParameterFromUrl(): Chainer<string> {   // use this return type

  return cy.url().then(url => {
    const parameterFromUrl = url.match(/\d+$/)[0];

    return parameterFromUrl  // this works, modifies the return value of the chain
  }
}
```

Using the method:

```js
getParameterFromUrl()
  .then(parameter => {
    cy.log(parameter)
  })

// or
getParameterFromUrl().as('parameter')
```

Comment: yes it is a solution but not valid for me because I need to get the parameter and use it in a complete different point of the method so I can not enclose it its use within a then :(.
check the example of the solution I have added (that I dont like it too much)

Comment: But- you *are* using a then in your answer (to access the alias value).

Comment: yes but not calling the getParameterFromUrlMethod. as I explain I get the parameter from the URL but then this parameter must be taken in a lot of places in the code, so if I have to add the THEN WITHIN the getParamterFromUrl method is completely different and much more difficult. I dont know if I explain myself properly, but yes I am usisng a then but is not the same at all

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to set the alias inside the method, use the pattern Zoe gave you to set the alias outside of the test.

Then the caller of the method is able to dictate what alias is used.

```js
getParameterFromUrl().as('myFunnyAliasName')

...  // somewhere else

cy.get('@myFunnyAliasName').then(value => {
  cy.log(value)
})
```

It works the same as the examples given by Cypress, you have just pushed some of the code off to the method.

Comment: yes good idea also, set the alias outside the method but at the end is more or less the same

Answer (score 0):

That's never going to work as it is, simply because you're calling an async function.   The `url()` call **won't** return a value, but instead will fire a request that will be completed *somewhen in the future*, but never immediately. Therefore it's simply impossible to for your `getParameterFromUrl` to ever return the correct response, since by the time it returns the `url` call it depends on won't have completed.

There are two possible solutions to this problem.

First option:

Pass a callback function to `getParameterFromUrl`, so it calls the caller back whenever `url` finishes and has the full response available. This is the most common pattern in Javascript and you code is using it, sort of. A possible implementation would be this:

```
getParameterFromUrl(callback: ((url: string) => void)): string {
    cy.url().then(url => {
        cy.log(url);
        const parameterFromUrl = url.match(/\d+$/)[0];
        cy.log(paramterFromUrl);
        if (callback) callback(parameterFromUrl);     //If we've got a callback call it with the final return parameter.
    }
}
```

Here `getParameterFromUrl` takes a function as a parameter that if called when you got the final value, the caller can use it to know when the value is ready. So now you change your call sites to something like this:

```
onMyPageObject.getParameterFromUrl(url => {
    cy.log(url);
});
```

Note that you only use the final value inside the callback, not on the return value from the original call. This is important if there is code following this call.

Second option:

Make getParameterFromUrl return a `promise` instead, in line with more modern Javascript developments. This time we return an object that will notify the caller whenever it completes and get the available value. Using language features we can make it much simpler to work with:

```
getParameterFromUrl(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>(resolve => {
        cy.url().then(url => {
            cy.log(url);
            const parameterFromUrl = url.match(/\d+$/)[0];
            cy.log(paramterFromUrl);
            resolve(parameterFromUrl);     //Resolve our promise with the proper value to return.
        }
    );
}
```

The apparent simplicity comes from the `async` behavior that gives the illusion of lineal execution, when in fact it's not and will run in pretty much the same order as before. The caller needs to be modified to use this too:

```
const parameter = await onMyPageObject.getParameterFromUrl();
cy.log(parameter);
```

This requires the containing function to be `async` too, which will enforce to make it all the way to the top of the call tree, but hopefully it results in more natural looking code easier to understand. Of course you could also code a `.then` call too, to the same effect if you want to avoid massive rewrites.

Comment: The second option won't work as you expect, as `cy.url()` does not return a string, but returns a `Chainable<string>`. Additionally, Cypress commands are not promises, and should not be treated as such: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#The-Cypress-Command-Queue

Comment: @agoff Thanks, now it's fixed, didn't know that it wasn't actually a normal promise, but an object with an unrelated `then` method.

Comment: No worries! It's always a bit of confusion, since Cypress commands look like they should be a promise (and actually runs on Bluebird's promises) but it doesn't like to behave like a promise :D

Answer (score 0):

ok I found a solution but I don't like it too much since future developers will have to go inside the method to check the alias name because are in different classes

```
getParameterFromUrl(alias:string){
  cy.url().then(url => {
    cy.log(url);
    const parameterFromUrl = url.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    cy.log(paramterFromUrl);
    cy.wrap(paramterFromUrl).as(alias)
  }
}
```

then in the other class

```
getParameterFromUrl(parameter)

//in a complete different point in the tests

cy.get<string>('@parameter').then(parameter => {
  cy.log(parameter)
}
```

this works as is explained in the official doc @jonrsharpe as I told you, but have several issues.
I can not directly use this.parameter in the second class because this fails, the second thing is that future developers may use this @parameter a lot of lines above and the will have to look for the method that actually will define the alias and go inside to check the alias name.
One option is add the alias as a parameter, but again it must be look in the code since it is a string typed in a method, not a real variable.
Also all that will use this parameter will be enclosed within a new then() command that will make the code very difficult to read.

so yes this solution works but I think it should be a better one